# Understanding .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to change my url type with .htaccess but I have a few problems. I tried a few online tools but they even do not work for me. So here what I am trying to do;

I have pages like `http://mydomain.com/profile.php?u=newuser` and I want to make as this: `http://mydomain.com/newuser` but so far I could not achieve it.

Here also what I have tried;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?u=$1
```

After making changes in .htaccess, do I also have to make any changes in my php files? Also, when try to open `http://mydomain.com/newuser` I noticed that some of my images on the page are disappearing, what would be the reason for that? Thank you so much guys!

Comment: Did you try putting as / before (.*)? You are also going to need to be more specific than you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gotten quite far, but now you're rewriting every possible url in your domain to profile.php, including stuff like /images/logo.jpg for example.

The question is, what do you want to do with this? An easy way to go about is changing it to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?u=$1
```

The added 'RewriteCond' causes the rewriteengine to *only* rewrite urls that don't exist on the server, so your images will show up fine.

Personally, I think it might be better to add a /profile/ prefix to all your profile urls:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule profile/(.*) profile.php?u=$1
```

This will allow you to add new rewrite rules in the future, if you need them; it will also not give you issues if one of your users decides to go for a username called 'profile.php' or anything else that clashes with the existing urls on the server.

Comment: is there a way to escape from those kind of issues resulted from having http://domainname.com/username kind of structure?

Comment: Well my first example only rewrites for non-existant urls, so that should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're sending every request to profile.php (.*).  This is going to affect all the requests for images, resources, etc.

Add this line above your rule to exclude "real" resources:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```